# Stop Arrow Spam

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm doing my first game with Lua in college and I'm having a hard time part.
My char shoots arrows non-stop and I want it to have a delay to shot each arrow.

I tried to create functions to simulate a delay but it did not work

```
local function atkRight()
    system.setTapDelay(10)
    display.remove(char)
    char = display.newImageRect ( "Sprites/archerRight.png", 50, 60)
    char.x = display.contentCenterX
    char.y = display.contentCenterY+50
    physics.addBody (char, "static", { isSensor=false })
    char.myName = "char"

    local arrowRight = display.newImageRect ( "Sprites/arrowRight.png", 50, 5)
    arrowRight.x = display.contentCenterX+40
    arrowRight.y = display.contentCenterY+40
    physics.addBody (arrowRight, "dynamic", { bounce = 0 })
    arrowRight:setLinearVelocity(500, 0)
    arrowRight.gravityScale = 0
    arrowRight.myName = "arrowRight"
end

atkiconRight:addEventListener( "tap", atkRight )
```

I wish this attack function could only be executed every 0.5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to achieve this. The simplest way is probably to have your event callback check the time.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/getTimer.html

Store the time a shot was fired in a global variable.
When a shot is fired and there is a timestamp of a preceeding shot, check and only shoot if it is at least 0.5 seconds later.

Another way would be to remove the event listener and start a timer event that will re-add the event listener after 500ms. Or you have a global flag that prevents shooting and have a timer reset this flag every 500ms.

Which way to go is up to you.